# In Many to One Relationship how to delete child objects

Tags: java, jpa, many-to-one

Many to One :

When removing child object it shoud also remove parent object in Many-to-One relationship. While saving a single object in both parent and child it's working fine. But if I add more than one child object (2 or more) to one parent class, then how can I delete the child object from the list of child objects of one parent class?

Child POJO:

```
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name="id")
  private int id;
  @Column(name="cName")
  private String cName;  

  @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name="pId")
  private Parent parent
```

Parent POJO:

```
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name="id")
  private int id;
  @Column(name="pName")
  private String pName;
  @Column(name="address")
  private String address;
```

Comment: This page will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/q/21545682/1098601

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find the correct answer for your question in below link. There also same problem @kostja Explained very well.

[How to delete Child or Parent objects from Relationship?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21569970/how-to-delete-child-or-parent-objects-from-relationship)

Answer (score 0):

You get the Iterator of the Collections object of children which is present in the Parent. Then using the iterator iterate to the specific child which you wish to remove and remove the child and update the parent object.

How are you mapping the parent to children. Currently you have just mapped your children to parent. But your parent is not mapped to the children. There are 2 options

1. You can correct the parent mapping and add a set/list of children in parent.

   > ```
   > Set<ChildPojo> children;
   > ```
2. Or if your logic really needs such a broken mapping then you will have to first find all children which have the same parent and then delete the child which you wish to remove.

Comment: In many to one relationship, the relationship is applied from child object to parent object right that's why I mapped like that. And While deleting single child object from the table it will through exception. The exception like you cant delete Parent Class object. Thank you

Comment: Because your mapping is broken to delete child you will have to first unlink the parent. That is set the parent in the child object to null. Update the child and then delete

Comment: check my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21545682/many-to-one-relationship-while-removing-child-object-its-throwing-exception