# How to delete Child or Parent objects from Relationship?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-one, many-to-one

I did a small application with more relationships. Now I want to delete details of my table how can I delete I don't get any Idea to delete.

Relationships are like below:

> PanCard-->Employee  (Ono To One)
>
> Employee-->ProjectManger (bi-directional many-to-one association to Employee)
>
> Projects -->ProjectManager(bi-directional many-to-one association to Projects)

Now I want delete the data of one by one table data

Below is my POJO classes Code:

### PanCard.java

```
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name="id")
  private int id;
  @Column(name="pName")
  private String pName;
  @Column(name="pNumber")
  private int pNumber;    
  @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name="EId")
  private Employee employee;
```

### Employee.java

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;
@Column(name = "empFirstName")
private String empFirstName;
@Column(name = "empLastName")
private String empLastName;
@Column(name = "empDepartment")
private String empDepartment;   
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="pmId")      
private ProjectManager projectManager;
```

### ProjectManager.java

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

private String department;

private String managerFirstName;

private String managerLastName;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to Myemployee

@OneToMany(mappedBy="projectManager",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Employee> employee;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="projectManager",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Projects> projects;
```

### Projects.java

```
 @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name="id")
  private int id;
  @Column(name="projectName")
  private String projectName;
  @Column(name="projectDesc")
  private String projectDesc;     
  @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name="pmId")    
  private ProjectManager projectManager;
```

Now I want delete the tables data: From which table I should start deletion.

- If I want to delete `Pancard` I should delete `ProjectManager` because `Employee` have FK.
- If I want to delete `ProjectManager` it should delete the `Employee` and `Projects` but `Employee` have relationship with `PanCard` So it's not deleting.
- If I want to delete `Projects` it should delete `ProjectManager` but `ProjectManger` have relation ship with `Employee` So it's not deleting.

So from where I have to start deletion and how can I delete the I don't know.

Comment: Why are you creating seperate threads for the same question? Link to your previous question, http://stackoverflow.com/q/21545682/2968614

Comment: @Aditya I am sorry I don't know how link

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can start deleting from any table you like. However, if you want to use JPA for that, you will have to prevent constraint violations. You can do that by either

- deleting from the owning side, or
- unsetting the foreign keys on the owning entities and then deleting from the inverse side.

To clarify the relationship mappings:

- `PanCard` is the owning side of the relationship with `Employee`.
- `Employee` is the owning side of the relationship with `ProjectManager`.
- `Project` is the owning side of the relationship with the `ProjectManager`.

A general advice - do not use cascades from the many side. The outcome is mostly not what you would want - a constraint violation. If you delete an `Employee`, the removal is cascaded to the `ProjectManager`. Since a manager can have multiple employees, the foreign key constraint in the `Employee` table would be violated. So I would remove the cascade from `Employee` to `ProjectManager`.

Comment: Thank you sir. So in Which POJO classesI have to remove the CascadtType.ALL

Comment: You're welcome. I would restrict the cascade from Employee to ProjectManager and from Project to ProjectManager. You dont have to completely remove all cascading, but you should not need the REMOVE cascade.

Answer (score 0):

Why should you delete the project manager while deleting the employee?
It's not one to one relationship, there are other employees and other projects too under the same.

Comment: Thank you when i am deleting ProjectManager it's throwing exception like. Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`prabha`.`pancard`, CONSTRAINT `FK_pancard_EId` FOREIGN KEY (`EId`) REFERENCES `employee` (`id`)) DELETE FROM employee WHERE (id = ?)

Answer (score 0):

In short:

1. Get an open entitymanager
2. Begin a transaction
3. Remove the necessary references (i.e perform the operations you want to do, but ensure that afterwards all constraints are satisfied)
4. Commit the transaction
5. Close the entitymanager